# ASP .NET redirecting to login page again in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am facing a issue in login page developed in asp.net
Its redirecting to login page again in Jmeter. Done all correlations.
I have tried Follow Redirects and Automatically redirect option also
Tried all cookie manager options also and all suggestions provided in stack overflow threads.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try "all suggestions provided in stack overflow threads" as well as blindly changing JMeter test elements parameters.

What you should do is to

1. Get a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp)
2. Configure your browser to use the sniffer tool as the proxy
3. [Configure JMeter to use the sniffer tool as the proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
4. Run the login request(s) in the browser
5. Run the login request(s) in JMeter
6. Compare the requests: they have to be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be correlated)
7. Once the requests are the same - the responses must be the same and you should be logged in successfully

Just remember to pay attention to literally everything: [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) parameters, [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), request body, each minor detail could matter.

Check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for example steps.